# Can I convert a list with objects into a two dimensional array

Tags: c#, list, object, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

I don't know if this is possible in c# but it would be great if it was. I have a list of objects which is very easy to convert into an array with the code below:

```
object [] myArray = wrd.ToArray();
```

It works fine, but how do I convert the list with objects into a two dimensional array, where the elements from index 0 to 20 in the list will be on the first row in the two dimensional array. The elements from index 21 to 41 in the list should be on the second row in the two dimensional array. The elements from index 42 to 62 in the list should be on the third row in the two dimensional array etc. In other words there should be 20 elements in each row and there is 21 rows and 21 columns. Forinstens in the image [labyrint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbZ4L.png)  then the character 'B' should be reached at index [1,0]

But again I don't know if it's possible, but hopefully some very skilled person can help me out.

Comment: First off, how many elements do you want in each row? You say 20, then immediately contradict yourself by saying each row should have 21 columns. Which is it? Secondly, Stackoverflow isn't a free code-writing service. Show us an example of what you've tried and where you're running into problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Frauke Nonnenmacher, but an array index starts from 0 and not 1. So if you looked at the image then you would notice there are 21 characters in each row, but when you place them into a zero indexed array it will be 20 elements. That's why I wrote 20 elements. My problem is as described in my post. I want to convert my list with objects into a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop over the array and put the items into a 2d one.

```
// Pseudo code...
x = 0
y = 0
loop while i < originalArray.Length

    2dArray[x,y] = originalArray[i]
    i++
    y++

    if y >= 2dArrayRowLength
        x++
        y=0

end loop
```

But really, why bother. 2D arrays in C# don't actually change anything about how the data is stored, they are just syntactical suger for accessing a single dimensional array in a slightly different way. Just calculate your x & y offsets on the fly as you access your single dimensional array.

Something a bit like this.

```
object[] data = new object[100];

int xLength = 21;
int yLength = 21;
for (int x = 0; x < xLength; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < yLength; y++)
    {
        var theValue = data[(yLength * x) + y];
        Console.Write(theValue);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```